# Unhandled exception in Service Fabric reliable service when PublishSingleFile is set to True

Tags: .net-core, azure-service-fabric

Here's a weird one that has me stumped.  I have a .NET Core application I deploy to a Service Fabric Cluster as a Reliable Service.  This worked great, until I added the last two lines to the CSPROJ file:

```
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <RuntimeIdentifier>win-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
    <PublishSingleFile>true</PublishSingleFile>  <-- New
    <PublishTrimmed>true</PublishTrimmed>  <-- New
```

This bundles up my program into a single EXE.  However, when I deploy it, SF tells me that the Application has stopped with an exit code of `3762504530`, which basically means some unhandled exception.  However, I can go into the node and go to D:\SvcFab_App\ and see the EXE and run it directly from the command line, and it starts up fine.

I then dug a bit through the Windows Event Log, and I see this error come up:

```
Application: DeviceSync.exe
CoreCLR Version: 4.700.20.26901
.NET Core Version: 3.1.6
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.GetType(QCallAssembly assembly, String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, ObjectHandleOnStack type, ObjectHandleOnStack keepAlive, ObjectHandleOnStack assemblyLoadContext)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.GetType(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase)
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.GetType(String name, Boolean throwOnError)
   at System.StartupHookProvider.CallStartupHook(StartupHookNameOrPath startupHook)
   at System.StartupHookProvider.ProcessStartupHooks()
```

I reverted my changes to the CSPROJ file and published again, it now it works great again.

My Question: When I use `PublishSingleFile`, why can I run my program just fine from the command line, but Service Fabric throws an exception when running the same app on the same VM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `<PublishTrimmed>true</PublishTrimmed>`. That is still experimental and might trim some valid dependency from standalone package. The reason it works when you run by logging into the node is that time it's outside the SF runtime and probably able to figure out from global.
Keep only the `<PublishSingleFile>true</PublishSingleFile>`.

If it still does not work, try to add nuget package reference of netstandard in your main host .csproj `<PackageReference Include="NETStandard.Library" Version="2.0.3" />`

Comment: Cool!  I'll play around with this tomorrow and see what I can come up with.  Thanks!

Comment: We've confirmed this fixes the issue.  Thanks so much!!